# Why does Typescript not give an error when indexing into non-indexable types, and is there a way to make it do so?

Tags: typescript, indexing, type-safety

While trying to use the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) type, I have repeatedly shot myself in the foot by trying to get and set elements using square brackets.  I realize that I need to be using `map.get(key)` and `map.set(key,value)` but after using Python and C# dictionaries for so long, I'm having a hard time getting this through my thick skull.

```
let m = new Map<string, string>();

// This doesn't generate any error, though it 
//  doesn't do what someone might assume it
//  would (doesn't add an element to the map)
m["foo"] = "bar"

// This doesn't generate an error either
m[1] = 2; 

// This does generate an error, even though
//  in javascript, m.foo means the same as 
//  m["foo"], so why does typescript treat
//  them differently?
m.foo = "bar"

// This is what someone really should be
//  doing to add an element to the map
m.set("baz", "qux")
```

The reason I use Typescript is usually because it prevents me from doing stupid things that the type does not support.  However, in this case Typescript does not give an error.  It doesn't seem to care that I'm trying to use square brackets to index into a map.

In fact, even for primitive data types like number it doesn't seem to mind me doing complete nonsense like this:

```
// Typescript allows you to index into any
//  type, even a number?!??!?!
let x = 3;
let y = 4;
x["crazy"] = "yes";

// But again the behaviour is inconsistent
// between indexing with [] versus .
// The following is an error in Typescript.
x.crazy = "no"
```

Or even my own class.

```
class MyClass {
    x: number;
}

let myInstance = new MyClass()
myInstance.x = 5;
myInstance["y"] = 10; // not an error
```

My questions are:

1. What is the rationale for Typescript allowing indexing into any and all types?
2. Considering that x.foo is synonymous with x["foo"] in javascript, why does Typescript treat them so differently?
3. Is there a way I can turn on additional checks which will prevent indexing into types which are not intended to be indexable?  Is there a way to mark a type as non-indexable so that you can't accidentally try to index into it?

Comment: Regard accessing map elements with square brackets have you considered starting from something [like that?](https://gist.github.com/attdona/502d67b99629592f368479ad8843b7d6)

Comment: attdona, yes I was originally using plain js objects as associative arrays, but assumed that I would get an improved type-safety experience by using the Map class, which turns out not really to be the case.  You are right that if you declare your object as ```[key: string]: Apple``` it will not allow you to use anything but an Apple as a value.  I was a bit surprised that it enforced this given my earlier experiment where I declared a ```    [index: number]: string``` but then it allowed me to do ```myInstance["y"] = 10``` without an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With default compiler settings you can indeed index into objects you shouldn't index into. This was probably done to ease migration from JS to TS.

You can enable the compiler checks regarding indexing (an other implicit uses of any) using the `noImplicitAny` flag, or more generally you can enable extra checks using the `strict` flag.

Comment: Thanks, I had read about ```noImplicitAny``` before posting this question, but I assumed it would not apply in this case because the compiler already knows the type of 'm' is 'Map<string,string>' from the assignment.   The descriptions i had read of ```noImplicitAny``` made me think that it had more to do with forcing you to declare the types of variables which typescript can't infer the type of automatically.    ```noImplicitAny``` solves it but is bit stronger of a constraint than I want, as I don't mind having some `any`-typed variables in my code.

Comment: @uglycoyote I know it's a bit more restrictive then just index signature checks, unfortunately there is no way to do just index checks .. there is a `suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors` but it actually suppresses the erros you want in `noImplicatAny` mode, so exactly the opposite of what you want

Comment: Maybe I'll make a github issue to plea for a new compiler option called ```noImplicitAnyUsingIndexing```, a weaker version of ```noImplicitAny``` which just disallows indexing on non-indexable types unless you explicitly cast to ```<any>```

Comment: @uglycoyote Sure, why not, there are already 100 compiler switches, what's one more :P

Answer (score 1):

The rationale of typescript allowing indexing is that the same semantic use of patterns for javascript has to be the same for typescript.

In this respect the property access `o.property` and `o['property']` have different expectations, see for example [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12596)

To add some more considerations, consider for example the javascript:

```
let x = 1
x["crazy"] = "yes"
x.pazzo =  "no"
```

This may be transformed into valid typescript in this way:

```
declare let x: any;

x = 1
x["crazy"] = "yes";
x.pazzo = "no"
```

or in this way:

```
x = 1
x["crazy"] = "yes";
(<any>x).pazzo = "no"
```

x is declared/casted to have any shape, so `x.pazzo` in this case become TS assignable.

The above behavoir make us assume that the primitive type number has an index signature `[string]: any`: this imply that a number can be indexed in TS like in JS.

With `noImplicitAny` option enabled the index signature `[string]: any` is no more permitted for number:

```
error TS7017: Index signature of object type implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

Finally to answer to the final question set `noImplicitAny: true` for enabling typescript to check for non indexable types.

Comment: ```noImplicitAny``` is indeed what I want.  I don't completely buy in to the explanation that "something valid for javascript has to be valid for typescript".  Javascript considers it valid to add new members to an object via the dot, e.g. my ```m.foo = "bar"``` example is valid javascript above but not valid typescript (assuming the type of m is expliicit or can be inferred from the assignment statement).  So it's not clear why TS would have a strict policy with regards to the dot operator but allow you (implicitly) ignore the type on your (explicitly) typed object using the [] operator.

Comment: Thanks @uglycoyote for the comment! You are right, My answer was quite imprecise, I updated the answer with some more info. I hope it is more clear.